# Include angular material into angular

Tags: angular, module, angular-material

I am creating an angular app with date picker input field, I did some digging I found the most suit module for this is angular material which is great.

the problem is I want to know if I included the material library into my code, does it include the whole modules and components into the app when I build the app. or it will include only the component that I am using only.

what I mean is suppose the angular material library is 5MG, and date picker component is 1MB, in the build phase, does it include the whole library 5MB or it includes only the component that I imported it only 1MB.

Comment: In Angular Material you imports ony what you need to.

Answer (score -1):

This will largely depend on how you include the Angular Material library. The modules are tree shakeable, so you are able to import just the modules you need.

A pattern that I've seen is creating a `MaterialModule` and importing and exporting only the modules you need from Angular Material.

It will look something like this:
`material.module.ts`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MatAutocompleteModule } from '@angular/material/autocomplete';
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';

const materialDesignModules = [
  MatAutocompleteModule,
  MatSelectModule,
];

@NgModule({
  exports: [...materialDesignModules],
})
export class MaterialDesignModule {}
```

You will then import this module where you need to use it.